# How to move the canvas backward in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, web-frontend

I try to think how the box can move backward when it hit 1000px (canvas.width) ,but I don’t know how it solves after If condition, so there’s my script, anyone can help me ?

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var canvasCT = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = 50;

function draw() {
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    canvasCT.fillStyle = "blue";
    canvasCT.fillRect(x, 50, 100, 100);
}

function run() {
    draw();
    x += 5 ;
    if (x > 1000) {
    ......
    }
}
setInterval(run, 10);
```

Comment: once you pass 1000, you need to start subtracting 5 from x each loop instead of adding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var canvasCT = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = 50;
var speed = 5;

function draw() {
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    canvasCT.fillStyle = "blue";
    canvasCT.fillRect(x, 50, 100, 100);
}

function run() {
    draw();
    x += speed;
    if (x > 1000 || x < 0) {
      speed = -speed;
    }
}
setInterval(run, 10);
```

```html
<canvas width=1000></canvas>
```